# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ''tax_query'' in wordpress

Tags: errors, tax-query, parse

hi i want to display posts by term.
first the code display all the posts:

```
 $aProjectArgs = array(
            'post_type' => 'uni_project',
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
            'orderby' => 'menu_order',
            'order' => 'asc'
);
```

so i add another part of code to display posts by term:

```
$aProjectArgs = array(
            'post_type' => 'uni_project',
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
            'orderby' => 'menu_order',
            'order' => 'asc'
            'tax_query' => array(
    array(
    'taxonomy' => 'post_tag',
    'field' => 'id',
    'terms' => 43
     )
  )
        );
```

but its not working its give me an error message`:Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ''tax_query''`

can someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

put `,` in 'order' => 'asc' 'tax_query'

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code with this one.

```
 $aProjectArgs = array(
                'post_type' => 'uni_project',
                'posts_per_page' => -1,
                'orderby' => 'menu_order',
                'order' => 'asc',
                'tax_query' => array(
        array(
        'taxonomy' => 'post_tag',
        'field' => 'id',
        'terms' => 43
         )
      )
            );
```